# Performance issue in sending email in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

**I am using below code to send email in Laravel 5.1**

```
Mail::send('Project.Emails.Award', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message
            ->to('EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress')
            ->subject('hi');
});
```

Here the problem is the above function takes min 5 seconds to complete the processing.

**Question** : Is there deliver async method s that I don't need to wait for the response ?

Comment: What mail driver are you using?

Comment: Have you considered using an API based mail provider? Something like Mandrill, or Mailgun. This would mean you wouldn't be waiting for the message to send, wouldn't have to worry about queuing at your end and it is either cheap or free, respectively.

Comment: @James: Can you please add the sample code for it's usage in Laravel 5.2 ? and I will accept it.

Comment: @Helper are you after an example of using email queuing or using an api based email provider and sending emails that way? I'm happy to provide set up for api sending but have not actually used email queuing before. I have looked in to it but ended up opting for using an api based provider as it saved me queuing and let a provider manage this for me.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `Mail::queue`. I am looking for anything that is free to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on which mail driver you are using or you have to use there may be other options to improve performance. However the most effective way to keep the UI responsive is [queueing the mail messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail).

With your code this would be as simple as:

```php
Mail::queue('Project.Emails.Award', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message
            ->to('EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress')
            ->subject('hi');
});
```

You though need to have [queueing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) set up and you won't be able to do this properly on some managed servers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this at the request of Helper, and to demonstrate an API approach to this.

As they're after something free to use, [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) is probably the best option as you get 10,000 emails free each month and then pay a small fee for each email after that.

[Laravel ships with the drivers ready](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail) to integrate in to Mailgun already and so to get started is actually really easy.

First off you just need to register for a Mailgun account and set up your domain:

1. [Register for Mailgun](https://mailgun.com/signup)
2. Set up your domain on Mailgun
3. Verify the domain and update your DNS records to prove ownership and to allow SPF and DKIM authentication

Once that's done you just need to configure your application to use it. [This guide](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-email-mailgun) covers the configuration of Mailgun on Laravel quite well, but essentially you:

1. Add Guzzle if you don't already have it (as you are sending your emails via an API to Mailgun to be queued and sent) `composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle=~5.0"`
2. Ensure your `config/services.php` file matches the below configuration so that we can keep our details safe and just store them in the `.env` file

i.e

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
  ],
```

3. Add the necessary fields to our `.env` file and populate them with the correct values

e.g

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=THE-DOMAIN-SETUP-IN-MAILGUN
MAILGUN_SECRET=THE-API-KEY-FOR-DOMAIN
```

Once you've set it all up, then you can simply use the `Mail::send()` command to send off emails like you were before - however it will be instant now (depending on your server - mine is pretty basic and sends emails instantly):

```
Mail::send('Project.Emails.Award', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message
            ->to('EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress')
            ->subject('hi');
});
```

Comment: Is there any other option which is 100% free to use ?